# InDesign: Even fontsize for pagenumbers in Table of Contents

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, formatting, table-of-contents

I am currently trying to make a table of contents in InDesign that houses two levels of headings. To make the hierarchy more clear I have changed the fontsize of the level 2 headings. My problem is, that this results in the page-number references to also have different sizes, which is not exactly what I want, since it looks rather odd.

[image: Table of contents with pagenumber references in different sizes]

If possible I would like to have those page numbers at the same (smaller) text-size. How can I achieve this? Will I have to manually style them?

---

Here a sample of how I would like it to look made in Photoshop

[image: Desired table of contents]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Toc panel, first click on "more Options".
Then, all you have to do is to create and apply a character style to the page numbers. Repeat for every entry.

[image]

Comment: Dang, how could I not see that. Thanks a bunch!